# how to pass returned data stored as a variable from a d3.json call as an argument to circle radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

This is bugging me little bit. I am making a d3.get.json with a callback to retrieve some data from an api. Works great. Then I am storing the key value in a variable which I am trying to pass as an argument to a circle. And that wont work. The circle wont get drawn. Cant seem to figure out what I am doing wrong

This is what I have

```
d3.json("http://data.cityofnewyork.us/resource/xm9j-adfx.json", function(data) {

    var energy = JSON.parse(data[0].consumption_gj_)/1000; // I probably will figure out a better math function for this
    //alert(energy)
    var x_axis = 10;
    var y_axis = 10;

    var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .style("background", "black");

    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(json)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle");

        var circleAttributes = circles
        .attr("cx", function(d){return d.x_axis;} )
        .attr("cx", function(d){return d.y_axis;} )
        .attr("r", function(d){return d.energy;} )
        .style("fill", "red");

});
```

Basically the idea is to draw the circle with a radius as a function to the energy variable

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/KcWCr/5/

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `.data(data)` and not `.data(json)` and you'll get the circles drawn.

You still need to to assign the circle attributes this way:

`.attr("cx", function(d){return d.x_axis;} )`

Comment: @Assaf--I tried all that. But it doesnt really work like that in case I think. I Just updated the fiddle in case you want to check it out

http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/KcWCr/5/

Comment: You need to follow the returned JSON structure. You don't have `x_axis` there. You do have `consumption_gj_` and `zip_code`, for example. Use them when you set the circles attributes.

Comment: ok i just resolved it myself :-)...i wouldn't have to the d.whaever...since i sam storing the data in a variable any way...so if i am writing a function to return the radius as an argument to the attr("r", )...it would look like this .attr("r", function(d){return what ever variable i am storing it in;} )

Answer (score 0):

ok for anyone who might be wondering how to resolve this....I just figured it myself...
here is the fiddle..(pat on my back)

```
http://jsfiddle.net/sghoush1/KcWCr/6/
```

The idea is once i store data in a variable using the callback fro the d3.json, I can easily use it as an argument to any attribute or style for generating shapes. Here is how I did it

```
d3.json("the external .json ", function(data) {

    var blablbla = JSON.parse(whatever key value I want to parse);
    //alert(energy)
    var x_axis = 10;
    var y_axis = 10;

    var svgContainer = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 300)
    .style("background", "black");

    var circles = svgContainer.selectAll("circle")
                  .data(data)
                  .enter()
                  .append("circle");

    var circleAttributes = circles
            .attr("cx", "50" )
            .attr("cy", "50" )
            .attr("r", function(d){return blablbla;} )
            .style("fill", "red");

});
```

and bingo!!